# I want to show motherboard information with powershell but change a parameter name output

Tags: windows, powershell, wmi, powershell-ise, motherboard

I want to rename `Product :` to `Motherboard :`

My code:

```
Get-WmiObject win32_baseboard | Format-List Product,Manufacturer
```

Output:

```
Product      : Nitro N50-600(DCH)
Manufacturer : Acer
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rename the property in PowerShell with a *calculated property expression*:

```
Get-WmiObject win32_baseboard | Format-List @{Name='MotherBoard';Expression='Product'},Manufacturer
```

In this case, we're telling `Format-List` to calculate a new property `Motherboard`, the value of which it should take from the existing `Product` property